# Long text box in ms access report

Tags: ms-access

I need to paste a very long text at the end of a MS Access report.
They're general purchase requirements that need to be printed on every doc.

I've tried to add them as a label but the character limit is 2048 and my text is way longer than that.

Any ideas how can I add that to my report?
I don't want to create a new table or a memo field just for that. Here's what I'm after:[image]

Comment: Add multiple labels with a paragraph of text in each?

Comment: My approach would be to add an unbound OLE object with a WordPad RTF document enclosed inside it. That way you can also control text formatting and font size. If you want, I can give a more full answer on how to achieve this in Access 2010, but it shouldn't be hard.

Comment: *I don't want to create a new table or a memo field just for that.* - Why not? It seems like the obvious choice. But if you need that text only on this one report, the OLE object is a good idea too.

Comment: Also consider a mail merge to Word.  That allows all of the formatting options of a word processing document combined with ability to import data fields.

Comment: If it is something fixed, why not use photo - image of the text well formated?

Answer (score 0):

Use an activeX label control instead of the standard label. A Microsoft Forms 2.0 label does not have the same limit on number of characters.

[image]